# Integration Methods in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I have noticed that there are several integration methods available in OpenModelica simulation setup. I dont know what these are. Can I get some sort of information regarding these? Will the quality of results vary if the integration methods are changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short document on the integration methods available in OpenModelica:
https://openmodelica.org/svn/OpenModelica/trunk/doc/SimulationRuntime/IntegrationAlgorithms/

Yes, the quality (simulation speed, even finding a solution) could vary if you choose
different methods. The default is dassl.

Comment: Is dassl the best solver and can it be applied to all kind of models?

Comment: I would say dassl is a good default. However, depending on the model sometimes other solvers would be better. Unfortunately I'm not a numeric expert so I cannot say more about it. Hopefully someone else would give you a better answer.